# Generation function for the finite Coxeter group of type $D_k$

Tags: group-theory, generating-functions, coxeter-groups, oeis

Basically I'd like to know how to derive the generation function for the finite Coxeter group of type $D_k$ to be familiar with notes in OEIS [A162288](http://oeis.org/A162288):

According to formula section:

'The growth series for the finite Coxeter group of type $D_k$ ($k\ge3$) has $G.f. = \prod_{i} (1-x^{m_i})/(1-x)$ where the $m_i$ are $[1,3,5,...,2k-3,k-1]$.

On the other hand Mathematica section of the sequence has a different formula:
$(1-x^n) \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (1-x^{2k})/(1-x)^n$.

In addition to that some draft correction has been provided recently:
'The growth series for the finite Coxeter group of type $D_k$ ($k \ge3$) has $g.f. = \prod_i ((1-x^{m_i})/(1-x))$ where the $m_i$ are $[2, 4, 6, ..., 2k-2; k]$.

Clarification on that topic to highlight the right formulas are highly welcomed.
Derivation of that formulas (from one to another) is also of right help.

Comment: Thanks for your question! Neil Sloane has fixed the sequences for $D_3, ..., D_{32}: A161435, A162207,...$ including A162288. Please verify. You may now delete or revise/edit this question as appropriate.

Comment: @Somos Thank you! I verified and it looks fine. Let me some time to revise the question to highlight my needs by now.